# Plotting a sinus function

Tags: python, function, numpy, plot

I try to plot a sinus function. But it throws an error" x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (1,) and (51,)" I can't understand they have same dimension. Why do I get this error? Thanks in advance.

```
%matplotlib notebook
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

from math import pi
from numpy import *



# spatial domain
xmin = 0
xmax = 1
n = 50 # num of grid points

# x grid of n points
x = np.linspace(xmin, xmax, n+1);

k=2


def f1(x):
    return np.sin(2*pi*k*x)


plt.plot(f1,x)
```

Comment: No, they do *not* have the same dimension.  Your `x` parameter is a function object; your `y` parameter is the vector `x`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the bottom of your program to be semantically correct:

```
plt.plot(f1(x),x)
plt.show()
```

`f1` is a function object; `f1(x)` is a vector of return values.